# Merge Sort Step by Step

Tags: sorting, mergesort

How would a merge sort step by step iteration look? I'm trying to grasp what happens in the merge sort. Ex. How would a list of values such as 25, 64, 22, 46, 20, 65, 90, 66, 48, 98 look step by step in a merge sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bottom-up merge sort:

```
25, 64, 22, 46, 20, 65, 90, 66, 48, 98   -> merge groups-of-1 ->
25, 64, 22, 46, 20, 65, 66, 90, 48, 98   -> merge groups-of-2 ->
22, 25, 46, 64, 20, 65, 66, 90, 48, 98   -> merge groups-of-4 ->
20, 22, 25, 46, 64, 65, 66, 90, 48, 98   -> merge groups-of-8 ->
20, 22, 25, 46, 48, 64, 65, 66, 90, 98   result
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this image found from wikipedia. Numbers are different but it's a good example of what the data would look like in each recursive call. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Merge_sort_algorithm_diagram.svg

Answer (score 1):

You can find some nice pictures of MergeSort (and others) on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort).